# Creating Image link with HTML Helper

Tags: laravel, image, laravel-4, anchor

I'm trying to create an image link with the HTML helper of Laravel 4. But it seems that isn't really working. I have this line of code

```
{{ HTML::link("#", HTML::image("img/logo.png", "Logo") ) }}
```

But that just outputs a strin like this:

```
<img src="http://localhost/worker/public/img/logo" alt="Logo">
```

How come.??

Comment: In laravel {{ $string }} outputs a "safe" string where html symbols like < and > are encoded. Try using {!! $string !!} instead to avoid encoding when needed. See more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253979/laravel-5-display-html-with-blade

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably will have to:

```
<a href="#">{{ HTML::image("img/logo.png", "Logo") }}</a>
```

Because, link() uses entities to escape the title:

```
public function link($url, $title = null, $attributes = array(), $secure = null)
{
    $url = $this->url->to($url, array(), $secure);

    if (is_null($title) or $title === false) $title = $url;

    return '<a href="'.$url.'"'.$this->attributes($attributes).'>'.$this->entities($title).'</a>';
}
```

Producing this source code:

```
"<a href="#">&lt;img src=&quot;http://localhost/img/logo.png&quot; alt=&quot;Logo&quot;&gt;</a>"
```

Answer (score 35):

I think it's overkill for no reason.
I would do:

```
<a href="#"><img src={{asset('img/logo.png')}} alt="Logo"></a>
```

If I then need a dynamic link in place of the #, I would do:

```
<a href="{{URL::to('/')}}"><img src={{asset('img/logo.png')}} alt="Logo"></a>
```

Try to use html as much as you can.

Answer (score 7):

You could also use html_entity_decode to get your code working

```
{{ html_entity_decode( HTML::link("#", HTML::image("img/logo.png", "Logo") ) ) }}
```

Comment: Excellent! That did the trick for me when trying to use bootstrap's glyphicon such as in `{{ html_entity_decode(Menu::item('home','<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span> Home')) }}`

Comment: This seems to be the most "Laravelish" approach? You could also wrap the above code in a custom helper function to clean it up.

Answer (score 3):

HTML helper has been removed from Laravel 5

now you could simple use this

```
<img src="{{ asset('logo.png') }}" alt="logo">
```

This asset by default point to public folder of your larval application

Answer (score 0):

Additional to correct answer also you can add some attribute like **height** and **width**

```
<a href="#">{{ HTML::image("img/logo.png", "Logo",array('height'=>'100','width'=>'100')) }}</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\Html::tag('a', \Html::image('image path')->toHtml(), ['href' => 'link']);
```

Comment: Thanks Anton and welcome to StackOverflow. Can you explain your answer or add a bit more details? This way your answer will be more usefull for people (and get upvotes)