# Displaying HTML with Blade shows the HTML code

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a string returned to one of my views, like this:

```
$text = '<p><strong>Lorem</strong> ipsum dolor <img src="images/test.jpg"></p>'
```

I'm trying to display it with Blade:

```
{{$text}}
```

However, the output is a raw string instead of rendered HTML. How do I display HTML with Blade in Laravel?

PS. PHP `echo()` displays the HTML correctly.

Comment: ```{!! nl2br($post->description) !!}``` works for me if I have only spaces and br.

Comment: The alternative I just provided is better than using {!! !!}, this is not very secure with third party html

Comment: For Laravel 8 working: ```{!! html_entity_decode($content_from_db) !!}```

Comment: @MuhammadShahzad answer works well. Tested on Laravel 9 after searching for a solution for a while. Thank you.

Answer (score 956, accepted):

You need to use

```
{!! $text !!}
```

The string will auto escape when using `{{ $text }}`.

Comment: Here are the Laravel docs that mention this: "If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax: `Hello, {!! $name !!}.`" https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data

Comment: I am also wondering about what @Ryan mentioned. Is this not a security issue?

Comment: @sanders It quite likely is a security issue if `$text` contains user input and you did not escape this properly. For example, `$text = 'Hello <b>'.$_GET['name'].'</b>';` is dangerous because `$_GET['name']` could include HTML, which would allow XSS. You could do `$text = 'Hello <b>'.htmlentities($_GET['name']).'</b>';` and would be safe.

Comment: this dose not do the whole trick! if I had something like `<meta cc="grâce à">` and I wanna show it in blade, It will look like this `<meta cc="gr&acirc;ce &agrave;">`. So the answer for me is @Praveen_Dabral 's

Comment: This prints out the content 3 times (duplicate), any idea?

Comment: This little things are golden knowledge!!

Comment: Because it's neither pointed out in this answer nor the comments: Apply caution to this syntax and **do not use it as your default way to output content in templates**! The exclamation marks are intentionally chosen to draw attention to the fact that you could become susceptible to [XSS attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) - especially when you output any strings provided by users (even when you don't expect them to contain markup)

Answer (score 84):

For laravel 5

```
{!!html_entity_decode($text)!!}
```

Figured out through this [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/rendering-html-from-database-table-to-view-blade-issue-or), see RachidLaasri answer

Comment: Thanks..its working..{!! html_entity_decode($data) !!}

Comment: This provides exactly the same result as the accepted answer, for the data given in the question. The only case where it would behave differently is if there were HTML entities in `$text`.

Answer (score 54):

You can try this:

```
{!! $text !!}
```

You should have a look at: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade#upgrade-5.0

Answer (score 34):

Please use

```
{!! $test !!}
```

Only in case of HTML while if you want to render data, sting etc. use

```
{{ $test }}
```

This is because when your blade file is compiled

`{{ $test }}` is converted to `<?php echo e($test) ?>`
while

`{!! $test !!}` is converted to `<?php echo $test ?>`

Answer (score 26):

There is another way. If object purpose is to render html you can implement `\Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Htmlable` contract that has `toHtml()` method.

Then you can render that object from blade like this: `{{ $someObject }}` (note, no need for `{!! !!}` syntax).

Also if you want to return html property and you know it will be html, use `\Illuminate\Support\HtmlString` class like this:

```
public function getProductDescription()
{
    return new HtmlString($this->description);
}
```

and then use it like `{{ $product->getProductDescription() }}`.

Of course be responsible when directly rendering raw html on page.

Comment: Returning HTML from a Form field Macro, this is exactly the right solution.  Return the HTML string from the function, using this method, and call the Macro within your Blade template. +1

Answer (score 25):

When your data contains HTML tags then use

```
{!! $text !!}
```

When your data doesn't contain HTML tags then use

```
{{ $text }}
```

Answer (score 14):

Try this. It worked for me.

```
{{ html_entity_decode($text) }}
```

In Laravel Blade template, {{ }} wil escape html. If you want to display html from controller in view, decode html from string.

Comment: this is not right is above answers it could be done in your way it just confusing the porgrammer

Answer (score 10):

You can do that using three ways first use if condition like below

```
{!! $text !!}
```

The is Second way

```
<td class="nowrap">
@if( $order->status == '0' )
    <button class="btn btn-danger">Inactive</button>
@else
    <button class="btn btn-success">Active</button>
@endif
</td>
```

The third and proper way for use ternary operator on blade

```
<td class="nowrap">
      {!! $order->status=='0' ? 
          '<button class="btn btn-danger">Inactive</button> : 
          '<button class="btn btn-success">Active</button> !!}
</td>
```

I hope the third way is perfect for used ternary operator on blade.

Answer (score 10):

you can do with many ways in laravel 5..

```
{!! $text !!}

{!! html_entity_decode($text) !!}
```

Comment: if you store encoded tags (&lt;p&gt;hello world.&lt;/p&gt;) in db above code works...Thanks!!!

Answer (score 9):

To add further explanation, code inside Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically passed through the `htmlspecialchars()` function that php provides. This function takes in a string and will find all reserved characters that HTML uses. Reserved characters are `&` `<` `>` and `"`. It will then replace these reserved characters with their HTML entity variant. Which are the following:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      Character      |       Entity     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          &          |       &amp;      |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          <          |       &lt;       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          >          |       &gt;       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          "          |       &quot;     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

For example, assume we have the following php statement:

```
$hello = "<b>Hello</b>";
```

Passed into blade as `{{ $hello }}` would yield the literal string you passed:

```
<b>Hello</b>
```

Under the hood, it would actually echo as `&lt;b&gt;Hello&lt;b&gt`

If we wanted to bypass this and actually render it as a bold tag, we escape the  `htmlspecialchars()` function by adding the escape syntax blade provides:

`{!! $hello !!}`

Note that we only use one curly brace.

The output of the above would yield:

**Hello**

We could also utilise another handy function that php provides, which is the `html_entity_decode()` function. This will convert HTML entities to their respected HTML characters. Think of it as the reverse of `htmlspecialchars()`

For example say we have the following php statement:

```
$hello = "&lt;b&gt; Hello &lt;b&gt;";
```

We could now add this function to our escaped blade statement:

```
{!! html_entity_decode($hello) !!}
```

This will take the HTML entity `&lt;` and parse it as HTML code `<`, not just a string.

The same will apply with the greater than entity `&gt;`

which would yield

**Hello**

The whole point of escaping in the first place is to avoid XSS attacks. So be very careful when using escape syntax, **especially** if users in your application are providing the HTML themselves, they could inject their own code as they please.

Answer (score 7):

Use `{!! $text !!}`to display data without escaping it. Just be sure that you don’t do this with data that came from the user and has not been cleaned.

Answer (score 7):

> By default, Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's `htmlspecialchars` function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

According to [the doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data), you must do the following to render your html in your Blade files:

```php
{!! $text !!}
```

> Be very careful when echoing content that is supplied by users of your application. You should typically use the escaped, double curly brace syntax to prevent XSS attacks when displaying user supplied data.

Answer (score 6):

This works fine for Laravel 5.6

```
<?php echo "$text"; ?>
```

In a different way

```
{!! $text !!}
```

It will not render HTML code and print as a string.

For more details open link:- [Display HTML with Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#displaying-data)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to escape the data use

```
{{ $html }}
```

If don't want to escape the data use

```
{!! $html !!}
```

But till Laravel-4 you can use

```
{{ HTML::link('/auth/logout', 'Sign Out', array('class' => 'btn btn-default btn-flat')) }}
```

When comes to Laravel-5

```
{!! HTML::link('/auth/logout', 'Sign Out', array('class' => 'btn btn-default btn-flat')) !!}
```

You can also do this with the PHP function

```
{{ html_entity_decode($data) }}
```

go through the PHP document for the parameters of this function

[html_entity_decode - php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It's worked:

```
@php 
   echo $text; 
@endphp
```

Answer (score 0):

For who using tinymce and markup within textarea:

```
{{ htmlspecialchars($text) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

**On controller.**

```
$your_variable = '';
$your_variable .= '<p>Hello world</p>';

return view('viewname')->with('your_variable', $your_variable)
```

**If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:**

```
{!! $your_variable !!}
```

**Output**

```
Hello world
```

Answer (score 0):

{!! !!} is **not safe**.

Read here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#displaying-data

You can try:

```
    @php 
     echo $variable; 
    @endphp
```

Comment: Is the same "not safe" echo and {!!  use it with care

Answer (score 0):

single brackets worked for me. double brackets showed single brackets on the page. i used

{! $text !}

Answer (score -1):

If you use the Bootstrap Collapse class sometimes `{!! $text !!}`
 is not worked for me but `{{ html_entity_decode($text) }}` is worked for me.

Answer (score -3):

I have been there and it was my fault. And very stupid one.

if you forget .blade extension in the file name, that file doesn't understand blade but runs php code. You should use

```
/resources/views/filename.blade.php
```

instead of

```
/resources/views/filename.php
```

hope this helps some one