# Output raw HTML from Laravel

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I have a `form` containing a `textarea` that stores user input in a table.

Currently when I pull this data in my view, `{{ $data->textarea }}` it outputs `<strong>` as `&lt;strong&gt;`. I'd like to either use or build a very basic WYSIWYG editor, but I don't think it will work if I can't output the raw HTML.

Is there some sort of attribute I need to define in my view or controller?

---

Meta: Would it be wiser to create a system like the Stack Exchange or Reddit where `**this is bold text**`?

Comment: Have you tried triple brackets? `{{{ $data->textarea }}}`

Comment: `{{ $data->textarea }}` escapes data try this `{{{ $data->textarea }}}`

Comment: @MarcellFülöp and Nitin Bhujbal using tripple braces actually escapes the data in [Laravel 4, by default it's not escaped](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates).

Comment: Yup it should be `{!! $data->textarea !!}` for laravel 5

Comment: Thanks all. @NitinBhujbal that worked perfectly. Laravel 5 docs for future reference http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5: Display HTML with Blade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253979/laravel-5-display-html-with-blade)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm assumng you're using the latest version of Laravel 5 because it escapes everything by default. If so then you need to use one brace and two exclamation marks to [tell Blade not to escape it](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates). This should do what you need:

```
{!! $data->textarea !!}
```