# Why is my laravel 5 rendering html as string instead of dom?

Tags: php, forms, laravel-5, laravel-blade

So I have written the following route:

```
Route::get('/login', function() {
    return View::make('login.form');
});
```

This is the view:

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <div class="form-section">
        {{ Form::open(
                array(
                    'url' => 'login-submit',
                    'method' => 'POST'
                )
            )
        }}

            {{ Form::submit('Authorize With AisisPlatform') }}
        {{ Form::close() }}
@stop
```

This is exactly what I see when I look at the page:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://app-response.tracking/login-submit" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="7xHzX20h1RZBnkTP2CRraZVsAfSQIfVP61mBiFtN"> <input type="submit" value="Authorize With AisisPlatform"> </form>
```

Um..... Shouldn't the form be well .... and actual form? Why did it render out the html as a **string**? How do I make it render the actual form submit button?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Laravel 5: Display HTML with Blade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253979/laravel-5-display-html-with-blade)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default echo braces: `{{ ... }}` escape HTML by default, to prevent HTML injection.

You should use `{!! .. !!}` to print raw HTML. For example:

```
{!! Form::submit('Authorize With AisisPlatform') !!}
```