# html tags are showing in my page as string

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel-5

I am using creditor in my larval site for post the data in my front panel. but the tags are shows like below example:

```
<b>text</b>
```

Then I was using strip_tags () function it show content only. But it doesn't take the functionality of tags. For Example:

`<b>text</b>` it shows: text

Not show like it: **text**

how to i show it correctly?

my code:View

```
 <div class="col-sm-1"></div> <div class="col-sm-10"><p class="about-para">   {{$row->description}}</p>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
public function save_terms(Request $request)
    {

        $page_title = $request->input('page_title');
        $description = $request->input('description');


        $v=validator::make($request->all(),
                [
                    'page_title'=>'required',
                    'description'=>'required',

                ]
                );

        if($v->fails())
        {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($v->errors());
        }
        else
        {


            $data=array(

                'page_title'=>$page_title,
                'description'=>strip_tags($description),

                'created_date'=>date('created_at'),

            );


            //$return= Terms_model::save_terms($data);
             $return = Terms_model::update_terms($data);
            if($return>0)
            {
               Session::flash ('message_insert', 'Record Inserted Successfully');
                return redirect('siteadmin_terms');
            }

        else {
 // Session::flash ('message_not_insert', 'Record not Inserted');
 return Redirect('siteadmin_terms');
```

}
            }

```
    }
```

Comment: strip_tags() removes the html and just puts only the text.

Comment: then how to show my content.. without using strip_tags() all tags are showing in my page

Comment: @kailashkumar What to show and what not to show?

Comment: if you want to that your page should display the tags behavior then why are using `strip_tags()`. If you want to keep specific tags then  pass the second argument to `strip_tags('your_string','<b><p>')`. So it will not remove the bold and paragraph tags from the string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5: Display HTML with Blade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253979/laravel-5-display-html-with-blade)

Comment: but strip_tags('your_string','<b><p>') show like only <b>text</b> and <p>text</p>. doesn't take tags.Its treat like a string

Comment: @kailashkumar https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade for escaping strings.

Comment: {!! html_entity_decode($row->description) !!} i entered like this format. still its not workout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel is escaping the string. Try with -

```
{!! $variable !!}
```

> By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks.

[Laravel Blade Template](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade)

Comment: This is not actually the problem with laravel but php function strip_tags()

Comment: @BhojendraNepal It is not a problem. OP wants `text` to be appeared in **bold**. But {{ $var }} will print `<b>text</b>`.

Comment: {!! html_entity_decode($row->description) !!} i entered like this format. still its not workout.  Also {!! $row->description !!} not work.

Comment: now it works. But some tags are not works for example italic tag, bold for particular word in a paragraph not works