# Retrieving data that was edited with Bootstrap wysihtm5 editor

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-wysihtml5

While retrieving data from database that was edited with Bootstrap wysihtml5 I am getting plain text as the screenshot. I am using Laravel 5.2 and MySQL.

How can I fix it?

[image]

in my view:

```
<div class="box">
        <div class="box-body">
          {{ $text->text }}
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Use `{!! $text->text !!}` to not escape it.

Comment: thanks .. it worked :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5: Display HTML with Blade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253979/laravel-5-display-html-with-blade)