# Outputing a page message in laravel

Tags: laravel, encoding

Hello I am trying to return a page message if a query fails to execute in laravel. It seems like the characters are escaped and the ouput is  instead of being bold 
the output is actually appears like this.

```
<strong>Failed!</strong> No Good
```

my code is

```
try {
       $product->save();
    } catch ( \Illuminate\Database\QueryException $e) {
       // var_dump($e->errorInfo);
        //$messageTest = "failed";
        $messageTest = "<strong>Failed!</strong> No good";
        $isSuccess = 0;
    }

     return view('admin.createProduct',compact('isSuccess','categories','messageTest'));
```

i call it with {{$messateTest}} in my view.

Any suggestions on the subject ?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: No, i am trying to bold the "Failed" part.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5: Display HTML with Blade](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253979/laravel-5-display-html-with-blade)

Answer (score 1):

This should work (the variable should be $messageTest):

```
@{{ $messageTest }}
```

It will not escape the html

Answer (score 1):

You should write inside the blade like below for view HTML Attr.

```
{!! $messateTest !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Blade `{{ }}` statements are automatically sent through PHP's
>   htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks.

You should try this:

```
{!! $messageTest !!}
```

> If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following
>   syntax:
>
> `{!! $variable !!}`

Hope this helps!