# Laravel Blade template not parsing html?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

New to Laravel and am currently playing with the Blade templating system. I have an issue with it parsing html. I have text data in my db with HTML tags (`<p>words words words`....) and when I used `{!! $post->content !!}` it came out the same with the tags showing. I tried clearing cache and even 3 brackets `{{{ $post->content }}}` but it's not working.

Comment: Version of Laravel? If > 5, it's `{!! $var !!}}`. Otherwise if < 5 it's `{{{ $var }}}`

Comment: All to it, including links to Laracasts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253979/laravel-5-display-html-with-blade

Answer (score 0):

When you write {{ $post->content }} it's not going to work. It will show the html tag.
But if you write {!! $post->content !!} it should not show the html tag, but it doesn't show the line break of course. so you need to write this one below -

```
{!! nl2br($post->content) !!}
```

It converts the newline to a <br> tag. This should perfectly work.