# How to put HTML inside a <td> in Laravel Blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to put Bootstrap Icon inside of my blade..But the problem is i couldn't get the actual output..Means here is the sample code:

```
@if (($row->is_management) === 1)
       <td> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> </td>
 @else
       <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></td>
 @endif
```

Means if status is 1 then green checked will come and in another condition red cross.

Can anyone suggest me what the actual mistake here?

Comment: more look like the icon font style css is not loaded on to the site. BTW may be this will help you:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253979/laravel-5-display-html-with-blade

Comment: nothing just blank

Comment: I don't see any error in controller as ..if i want to show `hello` in if condition and 'nothing' in else condition i could do that but when I go for  the icon,it  didn't come.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work on bootstrap css with glyphicons fonts. Please make sure that u have bootstrap css called and have glyphicons fonts

Answer (score 0):

```
 @if (($row->is_management) == 1)
       <td> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> </td>
 @else
       <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></td>
 @endif
```

Try this, use == instead of ===

Updated Code:

```
 @if (($row->is_management) == 1)
      {{ <td> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> </td> }}
 @else
      {{ <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></td> }}
 @endif
```

Comment: Also, can you only put `{{ $row->is_management }}` and let me know the result.