# How convert a data from database to html tags?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table with description of my products, in there I have column with html tags, when I get those data in modal, my data don`t follow the html. I need convert that?

I'm using Laravel 5.4. When I pass the value directly, the tag is recognized.

**My div tag**

```
 <div class="panel-body">
    <h5>Descrição</h5>
    {{$prod->description->erp_description}}
 </div>
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253979/laravel-5-display-html-with-blade

Comment: It works @Loko, thanks :D