# covert a string to html in php Laravel

Tags: php, html

I have a string, I want it to covert HTML as I print it to my blade.php file.

**String is like**

```
"<a href=\"http://localhost/myProject/shop/Tom-Shop/MjNzaGFkb3c=\">Tom</a>"
```

I have following code in my blade for output

```
<div class="commentText w100">
  <p >{{$comment['comment']}}</p>
</div>
```

but i code get executed same string comes to the paragraph,
I want to print anchor tag should get printed,

Note: I have tried php **htmlentities()** for this purpose and do R&D as much as i can but nothing worked for me .

Comment: Try `{!! $comment['comment'] !!}` to output without escaping

Comment: @VincentDecaux please post an answer. It deserve to be accepted

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29254016/4248328

Answer (score 6):

You Need to do like below:-

```
{!! $comment['comment'] !!}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use following syntax also :

```
<?php echo $comment['comment']; ?>
```

Or

In the way of laravel as follow :

```
{!! $comment['comment'] !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{!! html_entity_decode($comment['comment']) !!}
```

if you are using laravel 5