# Trying to load json data containing an html tags into html file

Tags: php, html, json

I have a json response with body containing an HTML tags:

```
{
    "total": 15,
    "per_page": 15,
    "current_page": 1,
    "last_page": 1,
    "next_page_url": null,
    "prev_page_url": null,
    "from": 1,
    "to": 15,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 48,
            "title": "Lamb Ribs with mashed potatoes",
            "body": "<p>Lamb Ribs with Mashed Potatoes:<br />230 grams of lamb ribs<br />Marinade:( Teaspoon pomegranate molasses, 1 tablespoon lemon juice, 1 teaspoon tomato paste, 1 teaspoon olive oil, salt, black pepper, &nbsp;oregano)<br />Marinate the ribs for at least 2 hours. &nbsp;Heat a non stick grilling skillet and grill the ribs from both sides untill done.<br /><br />Mashed Potatoes:<br />130 grams of peeled potatoes. Boil until cooked and let to cool.<br />Add a tablespoon of milk, salt, garlic powder and black pepper and mash together.<br />Serve immediately.<br /><br />545 calories<br />24.7 g fat<br />29.8 g carb<br />3.1 g fiber<br />48.3 g protein<br />.</p>",
            "excerpt": "",
            "format": "standard",
            "type": "recipe",
```

Notice: The above json is not full because it's long response file.

I have decoded the above json :

```
$post = json_decode($response);
```

And in view file:

```
{{$post->body}}
```

The text is loaded but its not formatted as supposed with tags.
[image]

In view source /chrome it appearing like this :-
[image]

How can i solve this ?

Comment: Try : `html_entity_decode($post->body)`

Comment: @VincentDecaux i tried but not worked ,, <td>{{htmlentities($post->body)}}</td>

Comment: @Ryan Vincent . What is the function i can use in view to send a raw output ? Please provide a solution

Comment: @Ryan Vincent i am using Blade template with laravel

Comment: I assume that you have found the answer already - whatever: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253979/laravel-5-display-html-with-blade

Comment: @RyanVincent this worked  
I assume that you have found the answer already - whatever: stackoverflow.com/questions/29253979/… – Ryan Vincent 1 hour ago please post it as answer

Comment: Thanks for the offer to make it an answer but I cannot add anything new to the answer so it isn't worthwhile. :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by using :-

```
{!! $text !!}
```