# Not allowing code to excute

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel 5, using {{  code }} will escape code and show it as text, but if the code is already encoded say HTML, and is displayed inside the {{ }} it will execute, is there a way for this not to happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5: Display HTML with Blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253979/laravel-5-display-html-with-blade)

Answer (score 0):

Use `{!! $your_code !!}` instead of `{{ }}`

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax: `{!! $text !!}` to display html

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#displaying-data