# Outputing HTML with PHP7 null coalesce

Tags: php, php-7, null-coalescing-operator

I want to use PHP7's Null Coalesce feature to output HTML, is this possible?

```
<p>{{$site->address_line_2 ?? "<i>Address Line 2</i>"}}</p>
```

Im currently using Laravel and blade, and the above outputs

```
<i>Address Line 2</i>
```

As a string instead of a HTML `<i>` tag with the content `Address Line 2`

Comment: Feels like you neglected to tell us what kind of template engine you are using there …?

Comment: @CBroe apologies, amended the question

Comment: So this has very little to do with the coalesce operator then, and your actual question is, how do I output “unescaped” HTML using blade syntax ... which you actually could have researched.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253979/laravel-5-display-html-with-blade

Comment: Try {!! $text !!}

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5: Display HTML with Blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253979/laravel-5-display-html-with-blade)

Comment: Of course, my mistake! I had it in my head that null coalesce outputted purely as a string or something instead of looking at my template engine. `{!!<i>Address Line 2</i>!!}` worked perfectly.