# How to render HTML from string?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a PHP variable in Laravel controller: `$html= '<img src="/example.png">'`

Then in view blade, I displayed it with `{{$html}}`.

But it isn't rendered as html element. It shows as a text/string like `<img src="/example.png">` in browser.

Answer (score 3):

You should use:

```
{!! $html !!}
```

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253979/laravel-5-display-html-with-blade), it is also documented on the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade), on the section Displaying Unescaped Data

Comment: Anyone reading this, just remember that *unescaped* means **dangerous** if any part of the string comes from user input.

Answer (score 0):

Displaying Unescaped Data

**By default**, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:

```
Hello, {!! $name !!}.
```

Ref. https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#displaying-data