# Laravel Blade : HTML Tags not rendered in my blade file

Tags: php, html, laravel, wysiwyg

So I have a WYSIWYG fields in my form and upon retrieving the data, html tags are not properly rendered. HTML tags are still displayed in the form. I have tried some solutions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253979/laravel-5-display-html-with-blade) and I also believe that it is the best way to parse HTML tags in laravel blade. I also tried doing it this way:

```
{!! nl2br(e($test)) !!}
```

And it still fails. Data displayed is still raw data.

**DATA**

```
<p><strong>Lorem</strong> ipsum dolor asdjfgjasfgbjgj gjbhgjgjgjkghkj; lkfakj ;ljljfl sdfadfasfd asera
```

**blade file**

```
@php
    $rules = $room['house_rules'];
@endphp
<div class="form-group">
    <textarea id="house_rules" name="house_rules" class="form-control" rows="4" disabled>{!! $rules !!} </textarea>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

**DD data**

`<p><strong>Lorem</strong> ipsum dolor asdjfgjasfgbjgj gjbhgjgjgjkghkj; lkfakj ;ljljfl sdfadfasfd asera`

Am I missing something that is causing the html to be not rendered properly?

Comment: pls show your full code: `blade.php file` and `dump(data)`

Comment: @EemJee You cannot render HTML inside of a textarea, it will be displayed as plain text but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4705848/rendering-html-inside-textarea) answer provides a solution with a editable div.

Comment: @Remul I think I already have used this to render data in textarea in my previous projects.

Comment: how are you expecting it to be rendered?

Comment: @lagbox Like the Lorem word will be bold in display.

Comment: how does the data have to be formatted in the textarea for your WYSIWYG editor to parse it correctly?

Comment: @EemJee Then you must have used javascript or a tool (ckeditor, summernote etc.) that replaced your textarea with a editor.

Comment: @Remul That's a good point. Since we are also using summernote :)

Answer (score 1):

When you've run your code through `e()` method, the tags will be changed to html named codes. For example, `<` will be converted `&lt;`. Running this through `{!! !!}}` will have no effect and it will just render `&lt;` which is `<`.

I would say that your best bet would be to render unescaped html `{!! $test !!}`. In this case however, you should purify harmful tags before saving to database (or before sending to blade for rendering). You can maybe have a middleware to filter out harmful tags.

Comment: Thanks but I have already tried this approach and still not working.

Comment: But, that is why html is not rendering properly. You are passing an already escaped (through e() function) code into {!! !!}. And, it will have no effect what so ever on the string. Browser is just rendering html named codes. Not the actual tags.

Comment: Yes I got you. passing the data to both `{{ $data }}` and {!! $data !!}` will not read the html tags as html tags but as normal text. And now, I have used `summernote` for it's what I'm also using in creating the wysiwyg data.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to apply html_entity_decode to your data to display the decoded data.

```
{!!html_entity_decode($item->body)!!}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because you have the `{!! nl2br(e($test)) !!}` inside the `{!! !!}` blade tags, which display nescaped data, meaning that the HTML are still present. In order to escape those HTML tags, use `{{ }}`.

> By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through
>   PHP's htmlentities function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use {!! !!}.

You can find more about this in official Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#displaying-data).

Comment: Hmm, strange. Maybe the data is wrongly stored in a database. Can you `dd($rules)` or `dd($test)`, and paste it in the comment or update your question.

Comment: I have updated. dd($rules) result is added, and my data is is still the same as stated in my DATA section above.

Comment: thats an old doc reference, its `htmlspecialchars` now ... the `e` method uses `htmlspecialchars`

Comment: @lagbox I pasted the wrong link, but just checked, for 6.x version this part is still the same. Updated the docs link.

Comment: @EemJee can you try to define new variable and put some random text in it with html template tags, and then try to display it in blade using both the `{!! !!}` and `{{ }}` tags

Comment: @zlatan I have tried your suggestions, but unfortunately, it's not working.