# Why does the content is not same from ckeditor to html page?

Tags: laravel, ckeditor

Hi everyone i got problem fetching the correct format data that i insert in the database from ckeditor. so in this case when i fetch the data from the database, the format that i make in ckeditor is not same in the html page. so to understand well, i will demonstrate what I am saying.

Programming Language: **Laravel**

**1. Illustration (listing number)**

[image: first illustration]

**2. Inserted data in the database .**

[image: second Illustration]

**3. Output**

[image: Output]

**Foreach Code:**

```
@foreach($bump_bar_not_working_solution as $bump_bar_not_working_solution_data)

<label style="font-size:14px;">{{strip_tags($bump_bar_not_working_solution_data->description)}}</label>

@endforeach
```

**Import CKeditor:**

```
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/16.0.0/classic/ckeditor.js"></script>
```

Hope Someone experience this.

Comment: You're using `strip_tags`. This will remove the php and html tags from a string.

Comment: even i remove that it result like this. <p>2.</p><p>3.</p><p>4.</p>

Comment: Use escape tags (`{!! !!}`). https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#displaying-data

Answer (score 0):

For laravel 5 you can use this code
`{!!html_entity_decode($text)!!}`

you can check this [link]: [Laravel 5: Display HTML with Blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253979/laravel-5-display-html-with-blade)

Answer (score 0):

Using this escape tags my problem is solved. ({!! !!}).

https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#displaying-data

**Thanks Rwd**