# I need replace variable php ->

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I have this variable in php with data but in some pages I don't have it defined so I need to replace it with some data but my code doesn't work.

`$item->restaurant->name`

Try with:

`$item->item_category->name = "Mi content replace";`

But it does not work.
What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: pls include all _relevant_ code. we can't tell from the little you put here. Can you do a `print_r($item)` and show inyour question what the output is?

Comment: _"it does not work"_ is not a problem description. Explain what is happening and what you expect to happen, and Include here the complete text of any error messages you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `PHP 7.0` you can use the null coalescing operator `??`. Which tries to fetch your `$variable` or else default to something else.

```
$nameOrDefault = $item->restaurant->name ?? "Mi content replace";
```

Or in a blade context

```
<p>
    {{ $item->restaurant->name ?? "Mi content replace" }}
</p>
```

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you so much!

Comment: How would you add html content for example:
<b>Mi content replace</b>

Comment: To escape html content {!! $html !!} see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253979/laravel-display-html-with-blade

Comment: But what if I don't want to use a variable and only enriched text, how would it be? Search but did not find.
Thanks

Comment: Hmm what do you mean by enriched text?

Comment: Example:
 <td>{{ $item->item_category->name ?? "!!<b>Mi content replace</b>!!"}}</td>

Comment: <td>{!! $item->item_category->name ?? "<b>Mi content replace</b>" !!}</td> you case is a little bit edgy, does this work?