# How to show quileditor's content with blade

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, rich-text-editor

Normally, v-html in vue would solve this issue, I dont know how to get around it using blade. Note, if i use the mustache syntax it would show the contents with the tags and thats not okay.. Please any help is appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel: Display HTML with Blade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253979/laravel-display-html-with-blade)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `{!! !!}` instead of `{{ }}`

```
{!! $content !!}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data

Comment: Wow that works...Thanks alot.Happy coding

Comment: Also, pls do you know how to make my quileditor have  a default value? Like a value from database

Comment: Sorry I don't know, I've never used Quill Editor.