# How can I display an html text as a function in the blade?

Tags: laravel, laravel-9

I want to display the text in the blade as html. To do this, I used this code in the controller section: ‌

```
class MessageController{
    public function customText($color): string
    {
        return '<p style="color: '. $color . '"><strong>Lorem</strong> ipsum dolor <img src="images/image.jpg"></p>';
    }

    public function show(){
        return view('1.blade',[
            'message' => $this->customText('#fff')
        ]);
    }
}
```

Now how can I function the same code above in blade ?

For example, I want it to be like this: ‌

```
{{message('#000')}}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Displaying HTML with Blade shows the HTML code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29253979/displaying-html-with-blade-shows-the-html-code)

Answer (score 0):

You can define the method in model, if you have a `message` instance, you can get it like this:

```
{!! $message->customText('#000') !!}
```

Or if there is no `message` instance, you can define your method as `static` and get the result like this:

```
{!! Message::customText('#000') !!}
```