# how to use blade Html:: class inside Html:: class in laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to display an image instead of word "back" to go to previous page how do i do that ?

```
 {!! Html::linkRoute('authors', Html::image(images/back.png)) !!}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as Html in L5.1 anymore, are you using a package?

Comment: there is dear, it's blade templating engine I am talking about

Comment: Can you point it where it is in the doc or source code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19007999/creating-image-link-with-html-helper

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates

Comment: No, @PeterPan666 is right. It's been taken out of the core, and you do need to pull that in through a package. It's also different from blade templates. Finally, whether you are using the laravel collective package or the original package, you can't do this with the HtmlBuilder because the link method automatically applies `htmlentities`.

Comment: Yeah thank you @moshin. You give us a link to the 5.0 doc where there is absolutely no reference of HTML class anywhere... HTML and Form have been deprecated since L5.0 has it's stated right here http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/upgrade#upgrade-5.0

Comment: ah my bad, sorry for that, I understand now

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that is not okay with your code is the missin single quotes

```
{!! Html::linkRoute('authors', Html::image('images/back.png')) !!}
```

but if that does not work, you can always use an `a` element

```
<a href="{{ route('authors') }}" title="Title">Html::image('images/back.png')</a>
```